# sap ui 5 fragment title long text

Tags: fragment, title, sapui5

Pls help me to set fragment with icon long text i.e. "Purchase Status" it print only "Purchase St..." on screen.
    code :

```
<IconTabFilter key="Purchase" text="Purchase Status" icon="sap-icon://order-status">
```

need help to print whole text on screen.

Mit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative which may suit your needs, if you really want to keep the icon - you can specify an IconTabFilterDesign of "Horizontal". This gives a little bit more space for the text. See an example [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBarProcess/preview) (this shows both the text property and a count property).

Answer (score 0):

The text display is aligned with the size of the icon, otherwise the long text will be cropped. If you really want to display all the text, just do not use the icon property.